# How to make carousel slide continuously with Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slide

I want to do, that logos with Owl Carousel plugin will slide continuously (no with 1,2,3... seconds delay, but slide without stop) Is it possible with Owl Carousel?

Comment: document of owl carousel is saying that there is an option to set infinite loop. option is - loop: true

Answer (score 12):

Here is how I got owl carousel to constantly scroll.

I had to add in a trigger to start the loop as the autoplay was too long, and meant it didn't start straight away, then I have a second trigger that sets the speed back to match the main setting.

You need to make sure that `autoplaySpeed` and `smartSpeed` are set to the same timing, and that `slideTransition` is set to linear.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    items: 6,
    autoplay: true,
    slideTransition: 'linear',
    autoplaySpeed: 6000,
    smartSpeed: 6000,
    center: true,
    });


    jQuery('.owl-carousel').trigger('play.owl.autoplay',[2000]);

    function setSpeed(){
        jQuery('.owl-carousel').trigger('play.owl.autoplay',[6000]);
    }

    setTimeout(setSpeed, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thnaks man!! Finaly someone got this. Really apreciate...

Comment: Hmm didn't work for me. Still stops at intervals. Just copied the code too.

Comment: I set the speed to 1000, then it was stopping and starting, but when I set the speed to 5000 it was continuous

Comment: smartSpeed is the important parameter here, without it, you'll get a non-linear continuous scroll that slows down and speeds up at slide change.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, using autoplaySpeed and autoplayTimeout:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    stagePadding: 0,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav: false,
    autoplay: true,
    slideTransition: 'linear',
    autoplayTimeout: 3000,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:2
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Without the smartspeed option, those settings won't do much. they will create a continuously scrolling slider, but the animation won't be linear and will slow/speed up at slide change. Adding smartspeed gives a continuous scroll at a regular speed, without 'stopping'

Answer (score 0):

You can define your slideSpeed and autoPlay status with;

```
$('#my_carousel').owlCarousel({
  autoPlay: true,
  slideSpeed: 200
});
```

But firstly; you should see the all options in the [Owl Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/)

Comment: Its not work, I want that logos will slide without stop, smooth. If I write slideSpeed: 200 , it slide like : slide - stop - slide -stop, but  I want that it will be smoother

Comment: Did you try slideSpeed:0 ?